# Android - proguard - Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I start a new APP with some dependencies which compiled in JDK1.6. The APP is built successfully in debug mode with proguard, but many warnings occurs as below.

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:<dependency package name> that doesn't come with an
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

In my proguard files, I have already add `-keep <dependency package name>{*;}` and `dontwarn <dependency package name>`. What should I do to make the warnings disappear instead of ignoring them?